# Performance Cost of a Memcopy in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, performance

So whenever I write code I always think about the performance implications. I've often wondered, what is the "cost" of using a memcopy relative to other functions in terms of performance?

For example, I may be writing a sequence of numbers to a static buffer and concentrate on a frame within the buffer, in order to keep the frame once I get to the end of the buffer, I might memcopy all of it to the beginning OR I can implement an algorithm to amortize the computation.

Comment: Have you ever gone beyond thinking about performance and measured it ?

Comment: I have, not for memcopy though.

Comment: Always thinking about performance is a great way to write crappy (and maybe slow) code.

Comment: `memcpy` can be optimized, but that involves assembly language, to use processor specific features, and for specific cases.  When thinking about optimizing `memcpy`, one must first ask why is memory copied in the first place.  Use smart pointers and references first.

Comment: @Thomas: be very careful, copying and referencing have both their purpose.  Using referencing as optimisation can be very dangerous (as I found out the hard way...)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

memcpy is generally optimized to maximize memory bandwidth of large copies.  Of course, it's not as fast as avoiding a copy completely, and for short copies of fixed size, direct assignment may be faster since memcpy has extra code to deal with odd lengths.

But when you need to copy a block of memory, it's hard to beat memcpy.  It's highly portable and most compilers go to great lengths to make it fast, whether that's using SIMD instructions or maybe inlining.

Comment: Use of memcpy in C++ should be avoided, since it's a "dumb" copy and bad things can result. The assignment operator/copy constructor should definitely be used alternatively. In addition, a profile should be run first to determine that it's the problem.

Comment: @DeadMG: Lots of C++ programs work on "dumb" data, which is called "plain old data" by the C++ standard and is perfectly safe to use memcpy on.  In my experience, the type of programs that don't have POD are the programs that would be better written in a higher-level language.

Comment: Yes. You *could* use memcpy and totally screw your program up with non-POD types. Or, you *could* use the assignment operator, which will ultimately result in a memcpy for POD types and a program that works for non-POD types.

Comment: Assignment operator won't result in calling `memcpy` for POD types.  It will result in binary image, which is the same result as `memcpy` with none of the optimizations.  A better approach is to use `std::copy`, which will do the right thing for non-POD types, and then specialize it (possibly using type traits) to call an optimized block copy such as `memcpy` where it's safe.

Answer (score 6):

It's ok to consider performance implications, but don't become too distracted from the real goal of writing good clean code.  If you are inclined to obsess about performance even when you know better, try to focus on higher level implications, and ignore the bit-by-bit stuff such as `memcpy`, which you can trust the compiler and library authors to optimize.

Generally avoid premature optimization of this low-level kind because it consumes your time, the effects bubble up to infect the entire program, and without measurements, you cannot expect to achieve any performance gains.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first - you should think about performance only if memory copying is your ***bottleneck*** *(and it's really a rare case).*

Second, `memcpy` is implemented using assembler (see `memcpy.asm`) and, I guess, is the fastest memory copying solution available.

*Also to mention, in general raw `memcpy` calls in C++ should be avoided, try using more abstracted wrappers and routines.*

Comment: Simple assignement may be implemented using CPU registers, but the use of memcpy is not the case. If the assignement is too large the registers the compiler would fall back to memcpy anyway, so better use the assignement (when applicable...)

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy()` copies the memory contents in source to dest. Copying obviously is linear to the amount of elements in the source. What constitutes the optimal size of an element is machine dependet. Anyway a lot of compiler otimization black magic can apply depending on the context of the operation. In C++ it is generally wiser to avoid `memcpy` and use assignment or copy constructors.

Comment: On a modern architecture, taking memory architecture and cache effects into account, copying almost certainly is not linear to number of elements. memcpy and copy constructor is comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 1):

Consider McCormick's  book 'Code Complete'.  Stealing shamelessly from there ---

1. Algorithm improvement usually has the biggest payback in performance.
2. Simple statements allow the compiler to optimize effectively.  These have low programmer cost.  They usually increase readability.  They are a low cost default 'should' anyway.

As mentioned `memcpy` has already been tweaked and is often really effective on larger memory blocks.  So why avoid it if the situation dictates keeping data?

In general do not optimize for no reason.  Suppose you write a report against a massive dataset.  No user expects to have an instant response in that scenario.  They start the job and go get a snack.  So if your code runs in 10 minutes or three minutes it doesn't matter.
To them. Thet won't notice. And... they write your paycheck.

Programmer optimization is a huge upfront cost.  So spend that cost only where needed.

Comment: Actually, it is Steve Mcconnell's Code Complete